# {!case.subject} is not populating in HTML email template

Tags: email-template

{!case.subject} is not populating in HTML email template.Is this a known bug?

Comment: No, that is not a known bug

Answer (score 0):

If all other fields are populating check the field level security.

Comment: all the other fields are populating and subject field has FLS for the respective profile.

Comment: Please try cloning the template and use it also make sure you see that field in preview some this happen with the template. I cloned it and worked for me.

Comment: I tried cloning it but the field is coming in preview but the moment I send the email using test email button the field again disappears.

Comment: Try sending it from workflow or apex if possible this seems to be a bug are you using system admin profile. also, try to change it as text and see the result. In the email try so view the source of the email some time outlook behave wired.

Comment: I am calling from process builder and using community plus user license.

Comment: That's fine what you see in text or visualforce format.  If the field is coming with those it can be an HTML parsing bug. try viewing in a different email client. if nothing help log a case with salesforce.